# Is there a Mean Average Recall for Item Retrieval/ Recommendation Systems?

Tags: recommender-system, model-evaluations, information-retrieval

[Mean Average Precision](https://ils.unc.edu/courses/2013_spring/inls509_001/lectures/10-EvaluationMetrics.pdf) for Information retrieval is computed using Average Precision @ k (AP@k).
AP@k is measured by first computing Precision @ k (P@k) and then averaging the P@k **only for the k's where the document in position k is relevant**. I still don't understand why the remaining P@k's are not used, but that is not my question.

My question is: is there an equivalent Mean Average Recall (MAR) and Average Recall @ k (AR@k)? Recall @ k (R@k) is simple to compute.

References:

- [How MAP Works](https://medium.com/@misty.mok/how-mean-average-precision-at-k-map-k-can-be-more-useful-than-other-evaluation-metrics-6881e0ee21a9)
- [Some examples](https://queirozf.com/entries/evaluation-metrics-for-ranking-problems-introduction-and-examples#precision-k)